# How to prove noise cause Constructive Eviction

Tags: rental-property, residential-lease, rent, michigan

I live in a building which was constructed in the 1930's in Lansing, MI.  I live in the back half of the building on the ground floor.  My bedroom wall neighbors a tattoo shop and there is another apartment above me.  The apartment is trendy and beautiful, and the price reflects that.  I have lived here and paid rent on time for half of a 12 month lease.

The noise has become intolerable.  I can hear and understand conversations held in the tattoo shop.  Every step my upstairs neighbor makes can be heard, and it's not quiet.  When his tv is on, we hear it.  I have recorded noise coming from the upstairs at 30-40 dbs (free phone app), and that is just the normal tv sound, not an "I have friends over" sound.

I have contacted my landlord and he responded with the neighbors email address, and a comment stating that he had never received a complaint about him before.

I will be moving out and I am hoping to reduce any fees or future rent that I may incur.  I've read that noise which is not addressed in a timely fashion can become a constructive eviction in Michigan.

Are there any steps I can take at this point to make sure I do not have to pay the remainder of the rent due when I move out due to the noise?

Comment: 30-40 dB is quite soft, so if that's accurate you may not have a very good case.

Comment: Up to 45dB is considered a quiet environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any steps I can take at this point to make sure I do not have to pay the remainder of the rent due when I move out due to the noise?

In Michigan you are only responsible for payment to your landlord until they find a new tenant, so if you find someone to move in when you move out and arrange a lease takeover then you would not owe anything.